# How to convert old project to WPF

Tags: wpf

We have lots of project developed using .net 2.0 version if I want to convert those project to WPF then what will be the approach. Please discuss in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to let the migration to WPF easy, be sure that your existing code doesnt contains a high coupling between GUI and your Business layer, if it's the case the most important step is to refactor your existing code, so your GUI code will contains only what's  related to GUI.

And after this step the part of your project to migrate will be not the big one, it will concerns only the GUI logic.

When I did this kind of migration from winform to WPF , we spent more time to remove coupling between GUI and other layers than to migrate the GUI layer, due to high coupling betwn GUI and other layers.

Answer (score 0):

Having gone through a similar exercise I'll tell you that it can be done but there are some challenges. 
Step1: Just for clarification when we say WPF some people mean Silvelright / web. WPF is not Silverlight so you need to clarify I want to migrate existing applicaitons to WPF thick client applications.  Since you stated WPF I am assuming you mean thich client/windows based applications so we'll go that route. (I'll mention SL at the end)

Step 2: Evaluate your projects from the code level for the most part refactoring the code is fairly easy. Since you are migrating from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0 I would really look at how many of your classes are defined, and see what can be refactored or in some isntances completely redesigned. THis leads us directly into step 3.

Step 3: Pick a design pattern. One of the tricky parts is coming to terms with a new design patterns such as MVVM for WPF. More than lilkely you will want to strip out and redesign the entire UI. As a result you will also want to utilize a proper design pattern (MVVM) or some flavor of that. This will also tie back to step two as some of your code will need to change to support your design pattern.

There are a ton of resources online for MVVM as well as UI development. If you are looking for reading materials I would look to WPF 4 unleashed as well as WPF illustrated. Both are good reads to help you get up to speed on the UI components how they work and the proper approach to using them in a project.

Get familar with .net 4 and the use of collections, types and of course the numerous new classes for wpf.

Disclaimer: You can in many instances create a WPF application usign tradition winform layout and practices. Whether this is right or wrong is a matter of opion of the developer.  My personal opinion is that yes you can forego learning new design patterns and use a winform approach but you will not gain the full benefit and capabilities of the framework using this approach.

And finally if you are planning to migrate these apps to the web (silverlight) your work will be a little more of a challenge. Silvelright does have a little higer learning curve and there are a few more rules (security, asynchronous calls, web services etc) that must be learned, and followed. I have foudn that in creating a migration that it is easier to migrate from Siverlight to WPF that vice versa. As Microsoft continues to improve Sivelright I think we will get to the point to where the code is interchangeable between the two patterns however right now it's not there.

Conduct a search online but here are a few links to help you get started:
Scott Guthrie (Silverlight) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx
Josh Smith (WPF MVVM)   http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/

best of luck